# Responsive React layout with a side nav

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I'm new in the React world and I was told to build a website similar to this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUWr.png)
I mean,I need to make a lyout where the header is always there and in the left side a nav qith different options but whn i open it in mobile screen that side navbar is hidden and a burger icon shows so when Iclick it it toggle the nav.
like this
[mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntuTk.png)
I have been working with MUI but im open to any suggestion to make it smooth and nice
thanks

I tried with MUI drawer but it overlapses in the screen and make anything  blurred. I want to always have the header shown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.